# Replace a full stop period \\. with space \\. space

Tags: java, regex

I want to separate a full stop period if it looks like a full stop period.

The first issue I have solved and that is:

```
// space period if followed by Capital letter having spaces before or not.
original = original.replaceAll("\\.(\\s?[A-Z])", " . $1");
```

This will do the following situation perfectly:
"Hello World. This is a Test of the SWAT Team.Here's another phrase. Both USA and EU as well as U.K have not commented it. `http://a.a.br`"

And do : "Hello World . This is a Test of the SWAT Team . Here's another phrase . Both USA and EU as well as U.K have not commented it. `http://a.a.br`"

Now, noticed that it separated the cases "Hello Word. This..." and "...SWAT Team.Here's". Also notice that it did not damage the URLs.

However it did not fix "...commented it. `http://a.a.br`" which should be "...commented it . `http://a.a.br`" But the world it. is followed by a lowercase http."

Now, I want it to separate the period like the other did if the word next has a space and a lowercase, or even a number provided that the period had a lower case letter before it.

So the cases:

1) "it. http" should be "it . http"
2) "it. 12" should be "it . 12"

Now this has to happen without damaging URLs or email addresses. Running the first rule "\.(\s?[A-Z])" will not damage email addresses and URLs.

Also, the problem with rule number 1 "\.(\s?[A-Z])" is that if, instead of an optional space and a capital letter, what if there is a line break before the capital letter [A-Z]?

So it it is "This sentence.\nThat sentence." It should result  "This sentence . \nThat sentence."

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can update the regular expression as follows to achieve this:

```
original = original.replaceAll("\\.(\\s[A-Za-z0-9])", " .$1")
```

The '\s' matches whitespace characters, so should be able to handle '\n'.
See http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html.

Tested using http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/.

Answer (score 0):

```
   re.sub(r"(\w{2,})\.",r"\1 . ",x,re.DOTALL)
```

It's in python and working for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requrement:

1. space period if followed by Capital letter having spaces before
   or not
2. space period if followed by (a space and a lowercase) or
   (a space and a number)

it could be input as below:

```
String test = "Hello World. This is a Test of the SWAT Team.Here's another phrase. Both USA and EU as well as UK have not commented it. http://a.a.br";    
test = test.replaceAll("\\.((?:\\s?[A-Z])|(?: (?:[a-z]|\\d)))", " . $1");
System.out.println(test);
```

The output is :

```
Hello World .  This is a Test of the SWAT Team . Here's another phrase .  Both USA and EU as well as UK have not commented it .  http://a.a.br
```