# How to insert spaces after full stops at the end of sentences, but not in abbreviations or floating point numbers?

Tags: java, regex

I have a JTextArea in which I want to replace all full stops without a space next to them e.g in "This is a sentence.This is another C.O.D sentence.This is yet another C.A.T. sentence." to "This is a sentence. This is another C.O.D sentence. This is yet another C.A.T. sentence.". But I don't want the abbreviations or floating point numbers to gain extra spaces e.g "This is a C.A.T. float 5.5" should not become "This is a C. A. T.  float 5. 5"! I am using string.replaceAll(".",". ") for this which is not proving to be sufficient.

Comment: Use some regex.

Comment: Do you want to replace "M.Twain" to "M. Twain" too?

Comment: See solutions for this https://stackoverflow.com/q/25056914/1737819

Comment: @Willmore No I don't want to replace "M.Twain" to "M. Twain".

Comment: @marvel308's solution changes "M.Twain" to "M. Twain" which is undesirable for abbreviations.

Comment: @hhj8i then tell us how would you distinguish an abbreviation? One letter following by period?

Comment: E.g C.O.D is an abbreviation or A.B.C. is another

Comment: @hhj8i not only an example, but clearly the definition. One upper case follow by period? Or simply uppercase follow by period? etc

Comment: And how should we distinguish this when it is obviously not an abbreviation:  `You and I.A quick brown fox` , and things looks like floating point number but not:  `Fact of World War 2.1 soldier has 2 guns`

Comment: This is a string.This is also a string, so uppercase characters won't do

Comment: @marvel308 What I said is uppercase followed by period, not period followed by uppercase

Comment: @AdrianShum Abbreviation is a group of words, with every group consisting of 1 or 2 letters and separated by a dot

Comment: @hh8i by your definition `he.lo` is an abbreviation, which is obviously wrong.  And are you ok that you treat `You and I.A quick brown fox` as abbreviation then?  Be clear on your requirement, and **update your question accordingly**

Comment: he.lo does not contain capital letters in them. It is not obviously wrong since the examples in the question openly show the letters to be capital! I.A is a special case and can be handled separately but You and me.A quick brown should not be treated as abbreviation because first group of letters does not contain any upper case letter.

Comment: @hhj8i In your definition you haven't say anything about "capital letters".  And by your definition `M.Twain` is also not abbreviation because the 2nd group is containing more than 2 letters. And, my example is `you and I.A quick brown Fox`, for which it is containing `I.A`.

Comment: M.Twain is not an abbreviation. I.A is an out lier and should be handled at the end when all other cases have been handled.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple, without negative look-behinds and such:

```
s = s.replaceAll("([^A-Z0-9.])\\.([^0-9 \t])", "$1. $2");
```

Replace the period when not:

- after a capital itself (U.N.C. or M.Twain)
- after a digit (1. - hoping the sentence does not end in a digit)
- after a period (...)
- before a digit (.5 - hoping the next sentence does not start with a digit)
- before a space or tab

Comment: By OP's (unclear) requirement, `HELLO.whatever` is not considered as abbreviation and should be replaced... (Honestly I think your solution is very reasonable.  It is more a problem of OP that failed to give a clear requirement)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regex

```
([^A-Z])\.(?!\d)
```

which replaces all "." not followed by a number and not preceded by a uppercase letter

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nz19p4/3), [online compiler](https://ideone.com/uK0lgM)

Comment: Regex in edited answer is deleting letter before dot!

Comment: it won't, you have to substitute with "(first group). " see the online compiler result

Answer (score 0):

(You should edit your question to clearly state your requirement, e.g. handling of abbreviation)

You could replace `(?<!\b[A-Z])\.(?!\d)` with `.<space>`

Demonstration: https://regex101.com/r/g1g7Yg/1

Explanation:

```
(?<!       )          negative look-behind group
    \b[A-Z]           word boundary following by one uppercase character
                      (i.e. one upper case character)
            \.        a dot
              (?!\d)  negative look-ahead group, of single digit
```

Which basically means, replace a dot if it is NOT preceded by single upper case character, and NOT followed by digit

There are still some flaws that it will not replace `Hello world.1 apple 1 day`.  It shouldn't be difficult to change the regex to fix this if you understand the above regex.